# How do I add my Ride sharing application in Apple Maps like Uber by using Extensions

Tags: ios, swift3, mapkit, apple-maps

I want to add my **ride sharing application** to Apple Maps like Uber or Lyft as shown in the below links:
[apps available for rides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia9PH.jpg)

[book rides through my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVvTB.jpg)

What do i need to do so that my application is available in maps setting Extensions.

Please help.

Comment: You should read the [App Extensions programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH20-SW1)

Comment: @saad-riaz did you find any solution ?

Comment: not an appropriate solution @Zeeshan